# What is the difference between using Email Alert and Email Quick Actions in Process Builder?

Tags: process-builder

There is a specific type of Quick Action, Email Quick Action, that can be used to send email from records. And there is the Email Alert, as well. Both can be used in the process builder, why would you choose one or the other?

Answer (score 1):

[Email alerts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_wfalerts.htm&type=5) are emails generated by an automated process and sent to designated recipients. These actions consist of the standard text and list of recipients for an email. You can associate email alerts with processes, flows, workflow rules, approval processes, or entitlement processes. They’re also available through the Invocable Actions REST API endpoint.

Whereas You can't use email quick action in process builder. [Quick actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_action_quick.htm&type=5) can be object-specific or global actions. Only **Create, Update, and Log a Call** actions are supported in the process builder. To use a quick action from a process, the action must exist in your organization.

[image]

Comment: So you are telling me I can’t use an email quick action with a custom template from a process builder ?

Comment: Yes, Process builder will not allow using quick action of type Send an email.

Comment: You can send emails using a custom template by installing this invocable action. It will then show up as one of the "Apex" actions that you can add: https://unofficialsf.com/send-rich-email-with-the-new-sendhtmlemail-action/